# Summation of all similar fields in the struct array

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose there is a struct array

```
struct Monthly {

        int totalLanded;
        int totalDeparted;
        int greatestLanded;
        int leastDeparted;

    };

    const int MONTHS = 12;
    Monthly travel[MONTHS];
```

Is there a method to summate all the values of totalLanded from all the members of the array with one statement, without using a loop?

So that it would look something like this ("pseudocode"):

```
int sum = summate(travel[].totalLanded)
```

Which would assign the sum of all totalLanded values from the entire struct array to sum.

Thanks

Comment: if you use `std::vector` instead of array for `Monthly travel[MONTHS];` you can easily write a `summate` function yourself, or even with array since its length is known as 12

Comment: I'm halfway sure there's a `std::sum` function, but that's probably using a loop. Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: @Ulrich

For no particular reason. 
Well, maybe for the sake of more concise code.
I'm a Software Development student. Just learning different ways to perform same task.

Comment: @macroland using vector instead of c-style array makes no difference for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to generate your sum. The first two arguments specifies the range over which the calculate a sum. The third argument specifies the initial value and type of the result. The last argument requires a closure or function that specifics how each element contributes to the sum.

```
#include <iterator> // For std::begin, std::end
#include <numeric>  // For std::accumulate

int main()
{
    const auto result = std::accumulate(
        std::begin(travel), // Iterate from here
        std::end(travel),   //  to here
        0,                  // Count starting at zero, return an int
        [](const auto sum, const auto & next) { // How to count each element
            return sum + next.totalLanded;
        });
}
```

For convenience, you an generalize the expression in a function template. Beware that the type of the initial value sets the type that will be used to accumulate the sum. If we use `0` as the initial value, the sum will be calculated with an `int` which may be problematic if the member is of another type, like `double`.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

template<class T, class M>
auto sum_members(const T & container, M member)
{
    // Deduce the type of the member
    // It's important to specify what type to use in the sum
    using t_element = decltype(*std::begin(container));
    using t_value = decltype(std::declval<t_element>().*member);

    return std::accumulate(
        std::begin(container),
        std::end(container),
        t_value{},
        [member](const auto sum, const auto & next) {
            return sum + (next.*member);
        });
}


int main()
{
    const auto total_landed = sum_members(travel, &Monthly::totalLanded);
    const auto total_departed = sum_members(travel, &Monthly::totalDeparted);
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard library function for this is [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).  You would use it like

```
auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(travel), 
                             std::end(travel), 
                             0, 
                             [](auto accum, const auto& m) { return accum + m.totalLanded; });
```

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3): it could be:

```
int sum = ranges::accumulate(travel, 0, std::plus<>{}, &Monthly::totalLanded);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fbda35329628681)